Saying "although it is unlikely but..."
There is one sentence from this page I am not certain about:

望み薄だと分かっていても正面から箱庭と交渉するかも知れない

It seems to me that 望み薄だと分かっていても is a way to say "although I understand it is unlikely but..." Is that right?


Did you look it up with a decent dictionary? What do you want to know beyond its dictionary definition?

As a native English speaker, I wouldn't phrase myself like that in the first place. If I say "although it is unlikely", the unlikely thing comes immediately after that, without "but" - because "although" already serves that connective purpose. It would be valid to say e.g. "I know it's unlikely, but...".

@KarlKnechtel Oh sorry, it was late in the night when I wrote this post, so I didn't notice that I used both "although" and "but". You are right that I meant to use "although" alone.

@naruto I did but it is not clear to me what might X refers to in Xが望み薄だと分かっていても. I am assuming that X refers to 正面から箱庭と交渉するの.

望み means "hope", not "possibility". 望み薄 means "unlikely to be successful", not "unlikely".

望み薄だと分かっていても正面から箱庭と交渉するかも知れない。
She might negotiate directly with Familie, even if she knows the chances of success are slim.
Despite knowing it's unlikely to go well, she might negotiate directly with Familie.

